# IntentFilter not working with HTTP redirect URL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, intentfilter

### TL;DR:

`IntentFilter` is not intercepting the URL when the LinkedIn authorization is finished and the navigation to the redirect URL occurs.

Looks like the `IntentFilter` cannot intercept URL like that, only if a new tab is opened, not when navigating.

And since LinkedIn only accepts redirect URL's with HTTP/HTTPS, I'm kind of locked on this issue. My only solution right now is to use a `WebView`.

---

I'm trying to add a "Login with LinkedIn" button to my `Xamarin.Forms` app. I'm using `Xamarin.Auth` with the `Custom Tabs` approach.

That means that in order to get the result of the login + authorization, I need to use an IntentFilter.
The auth using Google is working, since I copied it [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#android), but the auth using LinkedIn is not being intercepted by the `IntentFilter`.

I'm not sure what's wrong. Maybe the redirect URL is not correct, or maybe my `IntentFilter` has some issue.

I've tried to use different URL's, even `localhost:PORT` without success.

IntentFilter:

```
[Activity(Label = "LinkedInInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "http", "https" }, DataHost = "www.linkedin.com", DataPath = "/Act/Callback")]
public class LinkedInInterceptorActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Convert Android.Net.Url to Uri
        var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());

        //Load redirectUrl page
        Global.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri);

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        StartActivity(intent);

        Finish();
    }
}
```

LinkedIn config:

[image: RedirectUrls]

Comment: Have you tried to set the `DataPath` to `/oauth2redirect` like the sample in the link,and set `DataSchemes`  to the reversed client identifier that's obtained from the Android client id for the project on Google API Console

Comment: LinkedIn redirect URL's need to be a valid HTTP/HTTPS. I can't add custom schemes to it. And consequently I can't have different settings on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your authorization URL is correct.
It should be "/oauth/v2/authorization" you are using "/Act/Callback"

I am unfamiliar with the "Custom Tabs" approach, but I would imagine the same basic steps for authentication using OAuth are required.

Your redirect URLs should be where LinkedIn calls back to after a user authenticates on their site. This could be something like "http://www.yoursite.com/oauth/v2/linkedin".
Your app will need to be configured to listen on that address for incoming http or https connections. This usually is a web server, but at C# HttpListener will work as well. **Xamarin.Auth** may have this built in for you already, but I am unfamiliar with this exact implementation of OAuth. (You say it works for Google, so I imagine it does to some degree)

If your app runs independently across multiple devices, it may be impossible to add all the device addresses to the list of allowed redirects.
If this is the case you will have to set up your app(s) similar to this:

App notifies yoursite.com it is waiting for authentication. App directs user to LinkedIn for authentication. LinkedIn calls back yoursite.com (which is an allowed redirect) and sends the authentication result. yoursite.com relays the authentication result to the App which is waiting for an authentication result.

Regardless it seems like there is a little more than you think to the OAuth flow.
See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

For specific information on how to connect to LinkedIn using OAuth.

Comment: That's my `Redirect URL`. My `Authorization URL` is correct, the auth even works, it's just the `IntentFilter` that is not working. 

I don't have a website yet, that's why I'm trying to use URLs that don't exist.

Comment: The "Custom Tabs" approach is the one that uses the browser native UI to display the auth login. It means that the auth login won't be displayed in a WebView inside my app, but outside. That's why an `IntentFilter` is needed, to get the result when the user finishes authorization.